# What is an efficient way to increase and set the value of a dictionary key using python?

Tags: python, dictionary

This is basically what I'm attempting to do, which isn't working.  Is there a way to single out a value of the dictionary and mathify it?  For the sake of a crap example:

```
dictionaryNumbers = {'a':10,'b':10,'c':1,'d':1,'e':5,'f':1}
dictionaryNumbers['a'] += 5
#The goal would be dictionaryNumbers['a'] would equal 15.
```

---

EDIT:

Guys thanks for the feedback.  It seems there was a flaw in the order in which I was calling the functions to modify the collection.  I was printing the output before the math took place.  Thanks again.

Comment: There's no reason why that shouldn't work...

Comment: that looks fine. how's this thing inefficient?

Comment: `>>> dct = {'a':10, 'b':10}
>>> dct['a'] += 1
>>> dct['a']
11` -- what's not working?

Comment: That's exactly what happens. Open your terminal and type in `dictionaryNumbers = {'a':10,'b':10,'c':1,'d':1,'e':5,'f':1}; dictionaryNumbers['a'] += 5; print dictionaryNumbers['a']`. It prints `15`.

Comment: Can you show us the actual code that isn't working, or explain how your example isn't working as you desire?  As everyone has said, what you have here works, and seems to fit the requirements you outline.

Comment: I apologize for the confusion, fellas!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are mostly doing it right, and your code is working fine:

```
>>> dictionaryNumbers = {'a':10,'b':10,'c':1,'d':1,'e':5,'f':1}
>>> dictionaryNumbers['a'] += 5
>>> dictionaryNumbers['a']
15
```

but for any key not yet in the dict you'd have to test first (`if key not in dictionaryNumbers`) or use `.get()`:

```
>>> dictionaryNumbers['z'] = dictionaryNumbers.get('z', 0) + 3
```

which gets old fast.

But I'd use a [`collections.Counter()` class](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) instead:

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> counter = Counter()
>>> counter.update({'a':10,'b':10,'c':1,'d':1,'e':5,'f':1})
>>> counter
Counter({'a': 10, 'b': 10, 'e': 5, 'c': 1, 'd': 1, 'f': 1})
>>> counter['a'] += 5
>>> counter['a'] 
15
>>> counter.most_common(3)
[('a', 15), ('b', 10), ('e', 5)]
```

Advantages:

- No need to test for new keys; accessing a nonexisting key automatically assigns a count of 0
- Creating a new counter from a list of items to count is as easy as `Counter(items_to_count)`.
- You can sum counters; `counter1 + counter2` returns a new `Counter` with all values summed.
- You can subtract counters (negative values are removed), intersect them (find the minimum of either count), or create a union (maximum counts).